# Non-italic quote in the quote environment

Tags: beamer, lyx, quoting, italic

Any idea how to produce a quote in the `quote` environment that's not italicized (using LyX)?  I'm trying to create a presentation in `beamer` and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Does `\textrm{}` not work? Maybe `\emph{}`?!

Comment: If you want that *all* quote environments are typeset upright, then `\setbeamerfont{quote}{shape=\upshape,family=\rmfamily}` in the document preamble will do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can enclose the text inside a `\normalfont` group:

[image]

using some ERT:

[image]

In regular LaTeX, this would be equivalent to

```
\begin{quote}
This is some quote on the {\normalfont frame}.
\end{quote}
```